# hay alguna forma de instalar una extensión a chrome o firefox por php?

Tags: php, firefox, extensión-google-chrome

hice un sencilla extensión el cual quiero instalar junto con mi aplicacion la cual esta hecha en php

```
{

  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "modify-page",
  "version": "1.0",

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.ruat.gob.bo/vehiculos/consultageneral/InicioBusquedaVehiculo.jsf"],
      "js": ["cambiarcolor.js"]
    }
  ]

}


var simulator = document.getElementById('banner');
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("nav navbar-nav");
var y = document.getElementsByClassName("collapse navbar-collapse");
var a = document.getElementsByClassName("titulo");

var b = document.getElementsByClassName("subtitulo");
var c = document.getElementsByClassName("container sub_footer_frm cortaPalabras");
var d = document.getElementsByClassName("container-fluid arealink");
var e = document.getElementsByClassName("breadcrumb");
var f = document.getElementsByClassName("visible-sm visible-md visible-lg");
var g = document.getElementsByClassName("banner_movil visible-xs");


// if (simulator) {
    padre = simulator.parentNode;
        padre.removeChild(simulator);
        padre = x[0].parentNode;
        padre.removeChild(x[0]);
        padre = y[0].parentNode;
        padre.removeChild(y[0]);
        padre = a[0].parentNode;
        padre.removeChild(a[0]);
        padre = b[0].parentNode;
        padre.removeChild(b[0]);
        padre = c[0].parentNode;
        padre.removeChild(c[0]);
        padre = d[0].parentNode;
        padre.removeChild(d[0]);
        padre = e[0].parentNode;
        padre.removeChild(e[0]);
        padre = f[0].parentNode;
        padre.removeChild(f[0]);
        padre = g[0].parentNode;
        padre.removeChild(g[0]);
    // simulator.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    console.debug("no da");
// }
```

Answer (score 1):

No es posible, lo que puedes hacer es ubicar el link de descarga del plugin en algún lugar publico de tu aplicación. así insitar a la descarga del plugin.

También puedes poner una redirección a la descarga del plugin, pero esa forma es mas intrusiva para el usuario.

Saludos.

Comment: puedes explicarme a mas detalle tu segunda opcion?